# Does Evernote support RESTful API & webhook registration via API?

Tags: api, evernote

We're considering integrating Evernote features to our app.

May I ask two questions about the Evernote API?

**Q1:** Does Evernote support a RESTful API? The Developers site seems to offer only SDKs.

**Q2:** Can I register Evernote webhooks using the API? This is needed for us to help our non-programmer users register webhooks on their Evernote account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: Nope
Q2: Nope

I answered this question for someone in 2018.  Can't believe it's now going to be 2021.  They've just rewritten their frontend.  Let's hope the backend part is less painful and lengthy.